# Taking data from an sqlite table

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, swift3

I have an application and am using GRDB.swift to query data from an sqlite pool.

I made the initial configuration pot when I do the SELECT to get the right column that I need the app crash.

```
func loadCity(){
        do {

            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as NSString
            let databasePath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("data.sqlite")
            let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: databasePath)

            do {
                dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
                    //app crash here:
                    let poiTitles = String.fetchOne(db, "SELECT MUNICIPIO FROM municipios")
                    print(poiTitles!)
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("failed")
        }
    }
```

This is my sqlite data:
[image: This is my sqlite data:]

I believe my SELECT is right. What can I be doing wrong?

This is the error:
[image: This is the error]

Comment: Looks as if you did not create the table in that databas file.

Comment: The error "no such table: minicipios" means that the table is not present in the database file used by the application. The screenshot does not match.